# Show multiple media folders in admin panel m2.4.3-p2

Tags: permissions, media, magento2.4.3.p1

After 2.4.3-p1 all folders that are not in wysiwyg or catalog/category are hidden in admin panel, there is official instruction how to add folder [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/modify-image-library-permissions/#configxml). But we have multistore with more then 10 clients, and each customer have their own images and folders. Creating 10 extensions sound not very smart, and i can't figure out how to add multiple folders in one extension. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example link shows how to create multiple folders.

```
   <media_storage_configuration>
      <allowed_resources>
         <media_gallery_image_folders>
            <!-- new "Media Gallery Allowed" folders -->
            <my_image_folder>custom_folder_name</my_image_folder>
            <my_catalog_image_folder>catalog/custom_folder_name</my_catalog_image_folder>
         </media_gallery_image_folders>
      </allowed_resources>
   </media_storage_configuration>
</system>
```

In this case, `my_image_folder` and `my_catalog_image_folder` are two separate directories (one nested, the other not).  You can add as many as you want within the `<media_gallery_image_folders>` tag. Just use unique node names.